# Placing small spheres on the surface of a large sphere

Tags: geometry

I need to cover the surface of a large sphere ($R$) with small spheres ($r$),
where $R$ and $r$ are the radii of the large and small spheres, respectively.
Can someone indicate an algorithm that can compute the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the small spheres?

The figure below, is just a simple illustration of what I need:

!http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/SpherePacking_1000.gif

(the radius of the large sphere should not be equal to unity as in the figure).

Comment: An algorithm to do what? Count the number of spheres required given two sphere sizes?

Comment: To place them on the surface.

Comment: What do you mean by "cover"? There will always be parts of the surface that are visible.

Comment: That would be fine. I am actually searching for something quite elementary.

Comment: What I am actually asking is how to compute the x,y,z coordinates of the small spheres.

Comment: "Ditto" to ChrisM's answer. This is definitely a packing problem and belongs in a math group (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding a sphere with smaller spheres can be viewed as
packing disks on the surface, a heavily studied problem known as
the [*Thompson problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem).

---

[image: DiskPacking]

          

<sup>(Image from [Paul Sutcliffe](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0pms/my-projects/proj4_1213.html).)</sup>

---